# Working with Arrays which are stored in the .settings, cant initialize or set values

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2012, settings

I am trying to store an array in the settings of my program. I have referenced this other stackoverflow question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4267845/2916027) on how to make a System.Int32 array in the settings, but now I am having trouble actually using the array itself.

I would like to set the array size (int[100]) and then set/retrieve values from it like any other settings. Whenever i try to access or otherwise manipulate the property in any way, I get the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error, because the value is null. I'm trying to make it NOT null, but I can't because its already null, can anyone please help??

The array is called **InbatecCellPreference**

```
int preferlistcounter = 0;
Int32[] preferlist = new Int32[dgvPrefList.Rows.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < dgvPrefList.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //initialize the array
    Properties.Settings.Default.InbatecCellPreference.SetValue(0, i);

    if ((bool)dgvPrefList[0, i].Value == true)
    {
        preferlist[preferlistcounter] = Convert.ToInt16(dgvPrefList["CellID", i]);
        //set the array to the value of preferlist
        Properties.Settings.Default.InbatecCellPreference.SetValue(preferlist[preferlistcounter], preferlistcounter);
        preferlistcounter++;
    }
}
//save changes after the loop has completed
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

** UPDATE, I also realized that the setting Scope in the designer was set to APPLICATION instead of USER. Once i changed it to USER i was able to bypass the READ-ONLY problem**

Comment: what line is erroring?

Comment: the line right after the "//initialize the array" quote, but i suspect any of the lines where i try to alter the value of optimo_formation...inbateccellpreference would also error.

Comment: that would mean your setting is not actually instantiated, if it was your setting of a value you'd get index error... you are getting null ref. go into debug and verify that this setting variable is actually there.

Comment: the setting variable is there, it has a value of null

Comment: that means that it IS null

Comment: hmm, okay, so how can i fix this?

Comment: try this BEFORE your loop:  Optimo_Formation_Scheduler_C_sharp.Properties.Settings.Default.InbatecCellPreference = new Int32[dgvPrefList.Rows.Count];

Comment: ok, now i get a different error -- is read only cannot be assigned to

Comment: on the line I had you add?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738642/c-sharp-store-array-in-user-settings

Comment: the link I gave was for a 2D array but what matters was the list needed to be created.

Comment: if you post an answer i can mark it as such, this worked, thank you very much

Comment: look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738642/c-sharp-store-array-in-user-settings