# Store String Array with Values in Application Settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.5, application-settings, settings.settings

I've modified my Settings.settings file in order to have `system_Filters` be a `System.String[]`.
I would like to populate this variable within the Visual Studio designer and not from within the code. I can get it to work within the code using the following:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.system_Filters = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
string _systemFilters = Properties.Settings.Default.system_Filters;
```

This works correctly. However, I don't have a *nice* place to put this in my code and ideally want to type it in the Settings.setting file. This value will not be modified. I've tried almost every variant I can think of, but the result is always the same.

[image: cannot convert to System.String]

Does anyone know the correct syntax? I'm also open to using a `StringCollection` if that's easier.

Comment: You try to convert `string` containing C# code of array initialization "new string[] { .... }" to `string[]`.

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766610/how-to-store-int-array-in-application-settings/4267845#4267845

Comment: @abatishchev so what should I be doing? I have tried many, many different variants.

Comment: @SebastianPiu I tried throwing that entire XML string into the box and it complained as well.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try to use `StringCollection` instead of `string[]`. It is natively supported by the settings designer.

The value is stored as XML, but you don't need to edit it manually. When you select `StringCollection` in the Type column, the editor in the Value column changes; there is a <kbd>...</kbd> button, which opens a dialog to type the strings.

[image]

Comment: Do you know what to type in the `value` field in my Settings.settings file with a `StringCollection`?

Comment: Full name `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`