# Problems while adding items to an array in the settings.settings

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, application-settings

I am currently in the process of creating an application where the user will be able to create announcements. I would like to save the users announcements and have tried everything to save the user input in the form of a setting. Any suggestions/different methods for saving user input would be appreciated.

Current Setting's
[image]

My attempt at adding new "Announcements":

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Title[Properties.Settings.Default.MessageNum] = textBox1.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Message[Properties.Settings.Default.MessageNum] = textBox2.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.MessageNum++;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Error thrown

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

settings.settings xml file as requested

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="Title" Type="System.String[]" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="Message" Type="System.String[]" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="MessageNum" Type="System.Int32" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">0</Value>
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `StringCollection` instead of `string[]`. StringCollection is supported by VS.

[image]

Comment: Upon changing the code I started receiving this error {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: You've updated your question, and that `settings.settings xml file` should work now. But that exception sounds like a VS error, so try restarting it.

Comment: [Okay, have a look here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130448/store-string-array-with-values-in-application-settings)