# How to store user setting values in array?

Tags: c#, arrays, application-settings

I am storing values like this, but I want to store these values using array and want to load these values when I open program.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.VibratorValue1 = vibrator_numericUpDown1.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.VibratorValue2 = vibrator_numericUpDown2.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.VibratorValue3 = vibrator_numericUpDown3.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.VibratorValue4 = vibrator_numericUpDown4.Text;

    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private void Panel1_load(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    vib_numericUpDown1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.VibValue1;
    vib_numericUpDown2.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.VibValue2;
    vib_numericUpDown3.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.VibValue3;
    vib_numericUpDown4.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.VibValue4;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store String Array with Values in Application Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130448/store-string-array-with-values-in-application-settings)

Comment: I tried, it's not working. Getting error while loading .text values

Comment: Does it just "not work", or are there exceptions, broken or partial outputs, etc.? Following the steps in the selected answer works for me.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Experiment.exe but was not handled in user code

Comment: You need to initialize the array once (put default values in there using the settings designer).

Comment: can we do this in multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Not directly; you'll have to write code that serializes your data into a format (e.g. JSON) that can be stored using one of the supported setting data types.

Comment: yes, worked. How can i store values in Multi-dimension array?