# Array of structures in Application Settings

Tags: c#, windows, application-settings

What's a clean, canonical way to save a series of identically-structured simple config tuples in .NET [Application Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Say my program's got (user-scope) settings like "server name", "address", "port". I'd just add those three to the Application Settings as two strings and an int.
But what if my program's config needs to deal with multiple such servers, where the user can add and remove any number of them? I would want the settings to hold an array of triplets, each triplet made of two strings and an int, and the Application Settings don't quite seem to support that.

It's a relatively lightweight structure made of basic types, but so far the cleanest way I've found to do this is to create a new class(!) just to hold the array of triplets, fit the class with custom serialization/deserialization code, and then set it as the type of a single "setting".
I *could* do this, but considering how hands-off most of the Application Settings is, this really smells like something that's probably doable in a more straightforward way.

So is there such a way?

(Yes, I've seen the ["int[] array in application Settings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766610/how-to-store-int-array-in-application-settings) question, and the useful answers from there are not that useful in this situation.)

**ETA:** The point of the question isn't in server names or port numbers, it's in an *array* of identically-structured *tuples* of simple data, where each individual datum would be trivially saved.

Comment: why would you allow users to add and remove settings like that ..shouldn't you be the one setting it up ..? can you show a coded example of what you are trying to do and fyi the config file can have as may settings as you like in  regards to pointing to a particular server

Comment: I don't have any illustrative code to show, sorry. Assume my program is an equivalent of an IRC client, and the user needs to be able to set up (and save) connection details for multiple servers in the config, so he/she could connect to all those servers at a click of a button later.

Comment: Folks, when downvoting (or voting to close) a question that isn't blatantly unclear, unuseful or unresearched, please comment on what's wrong with the question. It will help me and readers learn how to ask better questions.

Comment: Application Settings isn't really the best place for this.  Typically one would just save the settings to an XML or JSON formatted file in %AppData% or %ProgramData%.

Comment: It sounds like you are equally interested in the setting being 'trivially read' as well as 'trivially saved'? Or do you not mind having a code method to parse the config?

Comment: @SamAxe, thanks, I'll definitely look into doing it that way too.

Comment: @RufusL, I was interested in trivial reading as much as in trivial writing, but I'll take what I can get :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider having a custom string for the value portion, one which you can parse (similar to a connection string), and then require a key name that begins with a constant, like `ServerString`. Then you can have a method in your code that reads all the keys that begin with this constant and parse the value portion into a Tuple.

For example, consider the app.config values:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ServerString1" value="name=MyServerName;address=127.0.0.1;port=80" />
    <add key="ServerString2" value="name=MyServerName;address=127.0.0.2;port=81" />
    <add key="ServerString3" value="name=MyServerName;address=127.0.0.3;port=82" />
  </appSettings>
```

And consider a method that knows how to parse a valid `value` string into a `Tuple<string, string, int>`:

```
private static Tuple<string, string, int> GetTupleFromServerSetting(string serverSetting)
{
    if (serverSetting == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("serverSetting");
    var settings = serverSetting.Split(';');

    if (settings.Length != 3) 
        throw new ArgumentException("One or more server settings is missing.", 
        "serverSetting");

    var name = string.Empty;
    var address = string.Empty;
    int port = 0;

    foreach (var setting in settings)
    {
        var settingParts = setting.Split('=');

        if (settingParts.Length != 2)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Setting is missing a value: {0}", setting),
                "serverSetting");

        switch (settingParts[0].ToLower())
        {
            case "name":
                name = settingParts[1];
                break;
            case "address":
                address = settingParts[1];
                break;
            case "port":
                port = int.Parse(settingParts[1]);
                break;
        }                
    }

    return new Tuple<string, string, int>(name, address, port);
}
```

Then, when you're parsing your app.config, you could do something like this to get a list of all the server settings:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, int>> serverSettings =
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Where(key =>
        key.StartsWith("ServerString", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        .Select(key => GetTupleFromServerSetting(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: It's better to use a serializer to code informations inside the application setting value instead of using a custom coded string.