# Storing Keys Array in Settings

Tags: c#

I have a Keys array called "KeyboardInput". How can I store it in Settings and then also read them out as seperate keys somewhat like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < KeyboardInput.Length; i++)
{
    KeyboardInput[i] = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), {{ Properties.Settings.Default.Keys[i]?? }});
}
```

`Keys[] KeyboardInput = { Keys.A, Keys.S, Keys.N, Keys.M, Keys.H, Keys.F, Keys.T, Keys.G, Keys.W, Keys.Q, Keys.Z, Keys.X, Keys.Right, Keys.Left, Keys.Up, Keys.Down };`

Comment: the Settings are stored in string format (XML), so you can join them all in one string and then split  the stored string and parse. Another approach is to look into XML or JSON serialization.

Comment: @EZI that doesnt seem to help in my case

Comment: @PRAGMA you want to save some settings and read them later, What am I missing?

Comment: @PRAGMA I think you can use any object instead of dictionary in that question.. What is different in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly the answer in the top [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766610/how-to-store-int-array-in-application-settings?rq=1) seems to work. After adding the setting, right click the Settings.settings in the Solution Explorer, Open With... any text editor, and change the type:

```
    <Setting Name="Keys" Type="System.Windows.Forms.Keys[]" Scope="User">
```

This will also update the `Settings.Designer.cs` file, and then you can use it like this:

```
Keys[] KeyboardInput = { Keys.A, Keys.S, Keys.N, Keys.M, Keys.H, Keys.F, Keys.T, Keys.G, 
                Keys.W, Keys.Q, Keys.Z, Keys.X, Keys.Right, Keys.Left, Keys.Up, Keys.Down };

Properties.Settings.Default.Keys = KeyboardInput;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

Keys[] keys = Properties.Settings.Default.Keys;
```

Comment: I ended up using your original comment, by doing .split(',') to read it :)